# Notepad++ delete everything in line after certain character?

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

I have seen and used many other tips and advice to help what I am doing. I'm not coding or anything, just working with normal text and messaging and I want to know how to delete everything in a line after the character I want which happens to be `*`. But I have almost everything with 2 `*` with words between that does not need to be deleted.

Example:

What I have

```
* Hello, how is everything * this is only a test
```

What I want to do

```
* Hello, how is everything *
```

I have multiple of these in my file with different things so wondering How do I delete everything after the second `*` in every line that has them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific example you gave you could use the Find/Replace window with a regex.

In the "Find what" box:

```
(.*\*.*\*).*
```

And in the "Replace with" box:

```
\1
```

Comment: that has worked perfectly, that was the last thing i needed to know for notepad++ man, thanks